# Get details from JSON response by sending http get request

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scrpping the following product details: 
https://www.ulta.com/invisible-physical-defense-sunscreen-spf-30?productId=pimprod2014440

I want to get the comment section by using http get request and then scrape data from response in json. I have make a request to scrape comments but unable to parse data like don't know how to get the required details from json response. I want to scrape following information of every user who give review: [image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import popen
import requests
import json


Opening Chrome In Debugging Mode
popen('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9014')

# declaring chrome optoins 
chrome_options = Options()

# Debug Address of Google Chrome (To Control Actuall Chrome Rather then BOT)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9014")
# Defining Driver
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

url1 = "https://www.ulta.com/invisible-physical-defense-sunscreen-spf-30?productId=pimprod2014440"

#chrome.maximize_window()
chrome.get(url1)

productPageUrl = chrome.current_url
productPageTitle = chrome.title
soup = BeautifulSoup(chrome.page_source, "lxml")

# productPrice = soup.find("div", class_="ProductPricingPanel").text.strip("Price")
productDetails = soup.find("div", class_="ProductDetail__productContent").text.strip()

http_get_request = 'https://display.powerreviews.com/m/6406/l/en_US/product/' + url1.split('=')[1] + '/reviews?apikey=daa0f241-c242-4483-afb7-4449942d1a2b'
json_data = requests.get(http_get_request)

parse_json = json_data.json()
print(parse_json)
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import csv


r = requests.get(
    "https://display.powerreviews.com/m/6406/l/en_US/product/pimprod2014440/reviews?apikey=daa0f241-c242-4483-afb7-4449942d1a2b").json()

with open("data.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Nickname", "Location", "Comment", "Date"])
    for item in r["results"][0]["reviews"]:
        writer.writerow([item["details"]["nickname"], item["details"]
                         ["location"], item["details"]["comments"], datetime.fromtimestamp(
            int(item["details"]["created_date"] / 1000))])
```

Output: [View-Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/7274ff444a31d2db8641e53151705750/data.csv)

[image]